# During rotation, the body bumps into the other two side by side (bug)

Tags: javascript, collision, matter.js

During rotation, the block runs into two static blocks side by side. How to prevent collisions?

[image: overlapping rectangles]

```js
var CELLSIZEPIX = 64;
var SPEED = 0.02;
var FRICTION = 0;
var RESTITUTION = 1;
var SLOP = 0.05;
var FRICTIONAIR = 0.2;

var tank;
var bodies = [];

var engine = Matter.Engine.create();
engine.world.gravity.y = 0;

var render = Matter.Render.create({
    element: document.getElementById("canvas_div"),
    engine: engine,
    options: {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        hasBounds: true,
        showAngleIndicator: true
    }
});

tank = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    64,
    64,
    110,
    90,
    {
        friction: FRICTION,
        frictionAir: FRICTIONAIR,
        frictionStatic: 10,
        dencity: 1,
        restitution: RESTITUTION,
        slop: SLOP
    }
);

bodies.push(tank);

var block1 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(0, 0, CELLSIZEPIX, CELLSIZEPIX, {
    friction: FRICTION,
    isStatic: true,
    restitution: RESTITUTION,
    slop: SLOP
});
bodies.push(block1);

var block2 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(128, 128, CELLSIZEPIX, CELLSIZEPIX, {
    friction: FRICTION,
    isStatic: true,
    restitution: RESTITUTION,
    slop: SLOP
});
bodies.push(block2);

Matter.World.add(engine.world, bodies);

Matter.Render.run(render);

var keyboards = {};

var eInfo = document.getElementById("info");

(function run() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(run);

    Matter.Engine.update(engine, 1000 / 60);

    for (var p in keyboards) {
        switch (+p) {
            case 65: { // A
                Matter.Body.rotate(tank, -0.02);
                break;
            }
            case 87: { // W
                var dx = -SPEED * Math.cos(tank.angle);
                var dy = -SPEED * Math.sin(tank.angle);
                Matter.Body.applyForce( tank, {x: tank.position.x, y: tank.position.y}, {x: dx, y: dy});
                break;
            }
            case 68: { // D
                Matter.Body.rotate(tank, 0.02);
                break;
            }
            case 83: { // S
                var dx = SPEED * Math.cos(tank.angle);
                var dy = SPEED * Math.sin(tank.angle);
                Matter.Body.applyForce( tank, {x: tank.position.x, y: tank.position.y}, {x: dx, y: dy});
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Matter.Render.lookAt(render, tank, { x: 200, y: 200 });

    eInfo.innerText = "Tank: x=" + (tank.position.x).toFixed(1) + ", y=" + (tank.position.y).toFixed(1) + ", angle=" + (tank.angle / Math.PI * 180).toFixed(1) + "\nBodies count=" + bodies.length;
})();

addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);

function onKeyDown(e) {
    keyboards[e.keyCode] = 1;
}

function onKeyUp(e) {
    delete keyboards[e.keyCode];
}
```

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/azdm9ns1/3/
You can move and rotate the central unit using the keys <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a limitation of Matter.js. See this question for workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321773/